# Error in connection with Apache Phoenix

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect with Apache Phoenix using Java API with the below code:

```
public class SampleHbasePhoenixConnection {
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:phoenix:hbaseServer:hbasePort:/";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database..");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT top 10 * FROM HBaseTable";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (st != null)
                    st.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the dependencies that I have added in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-HBase-2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-HBase-2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

The Hbase version that I am using is "1.2.0-cdh5.12.0". While running the code I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellComparatorImpl
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2254)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3985)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4788)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:241)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:150)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at SampleHbaseConnection.main(SampleHbaseConnection.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellComparatorImpl
    at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.util.KeyValueBuilder.get(KeyValueBuilder.java:71)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.<init>(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:398)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver$3.call(PhoenixDriver.java:248)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver$3.call(PhoenixDriver.java:241)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4791)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3584)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2372)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2335)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2250)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparatorImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

I have seen few other posts and I have created this connection URL using those posts only. I am not able to get rid of this exception. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your 4.0.0-incubating version of Phoenix Core is not compatible with the version of your Hbase client.

However you still have a second version of who seems compatible but unluckily not taken first at runtime.

Just delete this dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

If it is not enough, try upgrading Hbase Client version to 2.1.